# Refresh another activity from current activity

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-studio-3.0

is this possible to refresh another activity from current activity once I clicked a button in android so when I clicked that button it will refresh the other activity content?

Comment: You can use the `registerForActivityResult` api or a `LiveData` backed with a single `Repository`.

Answer (score 0):

You can update data source (ex. Repository) from first activity and than get updated data in the second activity.

Comment: so i gonna pass the new data to the new class?

Comment: @8xers6 usually we have something like: data source(backend/db/etc) -> VM/Presenter/etc -> Activity/Fragment. You can inject the same data source in different VM and call get\set methods in different activities.
You can read more for example [here](https://google-developer-training.github.io/android-developer-fundamentals-course-concepts-v2/unit-4-saving-user-data/lesson-10-storing-data-with-room/10-1-c-room-livedata-viewmodel/10-1-c-room-livedata-viewmodel.html)